# Expose socket.io listeners after client action

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is there a way to set up socket.io listeners for certain clients after they execute a command? For example:

```
socket.on('setupServer', function (data) {
    console.log("setupServer called");

    // Now set up listeners
    socket.on('serverAction', function (data) {
        console.log('Listener for clients calling setupServer');
    });

});
```

In the above, a client has connected and has issued a 'setupServer' command to the node.js server. The server now listens for 'serverAction' from the specific client. Other clients won't be able to use 'serverAction' without calling 'setupServer' first.

Comment: Have you tried this code yet? This should be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [room](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io#socketjoinnamestring-fnfunctionsocket) and validate some data from user and then join those users to that room, after that emit some events to that users in that room.

Something like this.

**server.js**

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection',function(socket){

socket.emit('auth_user')

socket.on('response_from_user',function(data){
    if(data.name === "Blashadow"){

        //join that user to the room
        socket.join('/room',function(){

            //emit some custom event to users in that room
            io.in('/room').emit('custom_event_room', { info: 'new used connected from room' });
            });    
        }
    });
});
```

**client.html**

```
var socket = io('localhost');

socket.on('auth_user', function (data) {
    socket.emit('response_from_user', { name : "Blashadow" });
});

socket.on('custom_event_room',function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```